# Perfoming search filter on my APIView in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to implement a search on multiple fields in my Django api, but I don't want to use generics or LISTApi to do that. Please, how can I accomplish that? I imported Django filter also to try to accomplish that but it didn't work.

Below is how my code is set up

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
class ListUsersView(APIView, MyPaginationMixin):
    '''
    Gets all the users in the database
    '''
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('email', 'name', 'profiles__skills')
    search_fields = ['email', 'name', 'profiles__skills']

    def get(self, request):
        page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer_context = {"request": request}
            serializer = self.serializer_class(page, context=serializer_context, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django_filters',
    ...
]


'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
```

urls.py

```
path('users/', qv.ListUsersView.as_view(), name='list-users'),
```

Comment: write your own filter class, and add it into your view like `filter_class=UserFilter`

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen please can you check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60725566/django-filter-on-an-apiview, it related to the Django filter